# Same font renders differently across FF7 and Chrome

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser, render

**Screenshot**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACTqz.png

It is pretty evident that my site renders different on Chrome and FF7 on my Win7 machine

I am using this:

```
h1, h2 {font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Helvetica Neue", Arial; }
```

Does anybody can point me how can I even these diffs? I don't want fonts with different 'feelings' on each browser.

The font, Lucida Grande is installed in my Windows machine

EDIT:
    font-weight: normal !important

doesn't work either

Comment: Try setting a specific font-weight, default values may vary across browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fonts will always render slightly different from one browser to another, but that was a bit more difference than usual. Probably because the headers have `font-weight: bold;` as default, and the font doesn't have a bold variation so the browsers create the bold style from the regular weight in different ways.

Anyway, you might want to use more common fonts. On my Windows 7 machine there is neither Lucida Grande nor Helvetica Neue, so it would render using Arial. Still, I have the additional fonts that come with both MS Office and Photoshop, so I have a lot more fonts installed than you can expect from a standard system.

Also, you should always specify a generic font as the last resort, in this case `sans serif`, otherwise it would render using the default font if none of the fonts are installed, which is something like `Times Roman` which has a completely different look. Perhaps also adding `Helvetica`, which is the closest equivalent of `Arial` on non-Windows systems.

Comment: I have Lucida Grande installed in my system, wouldn't that work? (hosted at localhost)

Just tried `font-weight:normal` !important. No go :/

Comment: @Hussain M Elius: That works as long as you are only viewing the page on your own computer, but if you want to publish the site you have to rely on the fonts installed on the visitor's computer. You might consider using a downloadable font, for example from http://www.google.com/webfonts

Comment: Hmm. I think I'll try a WebFont instead. Thanks for the help Guffa.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the two browsers are rendering it with a different *weight*.

I can think of two possibilities, though I don't know if either are correct.

- You requested a bold font, but that font is not available in bold.  One browser is just showing the regular, non-bold variant unchanged, whereas the other has processed it to look bold.
- You requested a particular weight of font, say "bold" or "600" but the installed fonts do not precisely match that weighting.  One browser is substituting an "extra-bold" variant of font, and the other a "regular-bold", or something of this nature.

If either of these is correct you could play around with the [font-weight CSS property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-boldness) to try and alter it.  But then that may affect substitution of whichever font is chosen in the case that it is viewed on a system with no Lucida Grande font at all.

Comment: Logical answer, except I have `{font-weight:normal !important}` set to the properties. The font "Lucida Grande" is also installed in my system. Right now I am just testing in my localhost and the problem is prominent even here.